# How to add next and previous button in access database using visual basic?

Tags: vb.net

I have used movePrevious() method and moveNext() method but that does not work once I search through the database. I mean that thing works fine when I first load the form but after I search for certain value and then try to use the button it dies not work. Remember I am just a beginner in visual basic.

```
Private Sub EmployeeBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Me.Validate()
    Me.EmployeeBindingSource.EndEdit()
    Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.CEMPLOYEEDataSet)
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Try
        Me.EmployeeTableAdapter.emp_id(Me.CEMPLOYEEDataSet.Employee, New System.Nullable(Of Integer)(CType(TextBox1.Text, Integer)))
    Catch ex As System.Exception
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub


Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    EmployeeBindingSource.MovePrevious()
End Sub

Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    EmployeeBindingSource.MoveNext()
End Sub
```

Picture of my form

[image]

Comment: where is the code for the MoveNext Method?

Comment: @codeMonger123 last line!! Button4.click

Comment: I see you are using a bindingsource rather than a Stored Procedure to get the data. I have not worked with binding sources for a long time however take a look at these http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/298800-bindingsourcemovenext-to-specific-acct%23/                       http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19949458/vb-net-bindingsource-and-bindingnavigation-programatically